# Invariant sets of planar system ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system:  $\ \dot{x}\  = -3xy, \ \dot{y}\  = -y + 3xy$.

(a) Prove that $X = \left\{(x,y)\in R^2: x+y\leq 1, x\geq 0, y\geq 0\right\}$ is a positively invariant set.

(b) Prove that for every initial condition in $X$, the orbit of the associated solution converges to an equlibrium as $t\rightarrow \infty$. Is every equilibrium in $X$ the $w$-limit set of a nonconstant orbit with initial condition in $X$?

**My attempt:** (a) At first I thought this question is wrong, since $\dot{x} + \dot{y}\neq 0$. But then I realized that for any points $(x,y)$ in $X$, since $\dot{x} + \dot{y} = - y \leq 0$, we see that every movements of the solutions, with respect to time $t$, starting on or below the boundary line $x+y = 1$ must go vertically down (not horizontally down, as $\dot{x} + \dot{y} = - y$). It's easy to see that the $x$-axis contains all the equilibrium points of the system, so it's invariant. Therefore, every solutions starting below the line $x+y = 1$ and going vertically down, cannot cross the $x$-axis. Note that we cannot guarantee invariance if any solutions go horizontally, since the $x$-axis is not invariant in this case, but fortunately none of the solutions can go horizontally in this case (Q.E.D)

Is my solution correct here?

(b) I got completely stucked on this part. Can anyone please help me on this part?

Comment: By $D$ you mean $X$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: definitely. I edited it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $X$ is compact, and its boundary consists of three line segments. $\{(x,0): 0 \le x \le 1\}$ consists of equilibrium points.  On $\{(0,y): 0 < y \le 1\}$, the vector field is pointing vertically down, so that segment is positively invariant.  On $\{(x,1-x): 0 < x < 1\}$, the vector field is pointing into 
the region $X$.  Therefore $X$ is positively invariant: an orbit that escapes $X$ would have to escape at some boundary point, and there is no boundary point at which that is possible.

(2a) In $X$, $\dot{x} \le 0$.  Can there be any periodic orbit or homoclinic/heteroclinic cycles there?

(2b) If $x > 1/3$ and $y \ge 0$, $\dot{y} > 0$.  What does that say about the possibility of $(x,0)$ being an $\omega$-limit set?

Comment: Thanks for your great proof in pary (a), Prof. Israel! But in part (2a), can you please elaborate further? I don't see how the hint implies anything about periodic or homoclinic/heteroclinic orbit (of course, at each level set $x+ y = c$ for $c\in [0,1]$, we have an equilibrium $(c,0)$, but these equilibriums would be on different orbits). The only thing I can see from $\dot{x}\leq 0$ is all solutions with initial conditions in X must move either left or vertically down. In the later case, they would converge to the equilibrium points on x-axis. Former case stumbles me.

Comment: You can't have a periodic or homoclinic/heteroclinic orbit if $x$ is never increasing.  What goes down must come up...

Comment: Thank you for your further explanation. But how does it prove the convergence of solutions in X to equilibrium points? In fact, the problem basically is saying to prove that all the equilibrium points are ASYMPTOTICALLY stable. I tried computing the eigenvalues of the linearized system with Df(x_0, y_0) for $x_0+y_0 = c$ $(c\in [0,1], x_0, y_0\geq 0)$, and I see that the equilibrium point $(\frac{1}{3}, 0)$ is not asymptotically stable, so when $c=\frac{1}{3}$, none of the orbits in $X$ can converge to any other equilibrium, because that equilibrium is not on the same orbit.

Comment: Note that I was able to show all equilibriums belong to orbits in $X$ with $c<\frac{1}{3}$ are asymptotically stable. For $c > \frac{1}{3}$, I haven't been able to show the same statement for cases when $x\geq \frac{1}{3}$. But for $x\geq \frac{1}{3}$, those equilibriums are not asymptotically stable, so how can the orbit solutions in $X$ with $c > \frac{1}{3}$  converge to $(c,0)$?

Comment: For your hint on part (2b): as $y$ is strictly increasing, the equilibrium point $(x,0)$ is unique for each $x>\frac{1}{3}$. By Poincare-Bendixon theorem, since the $w$-limit set cannot contained a closed orbit (due to your argument above for (2a)), we conclude that it must contain an equilibrium $(x,0)$, and its $w$-limit set is this equilibrium. But why we restrict ourselves to $x>\frac{1}{3}$? I find the Poincare-Bendixon theorem applies to both cases.

Comment: For $x > 1/3$, there are no orbits in $X$ (other than the equilibrium point itself) that have $\omega$-limit $(x,0)$, because $y$ would have to decrease as it approached $(x,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, Professor Israel! I'm so dumb:( Can you please see my question for part (a) in my 3rd comment (from the top), and help explain why there exists such convergence for non-asymptotically stable equilibrium point?

Comment: I think I got part (2a) now. We consider two cases: for $\dot{x} = 0$, then $\dot{y}\leq 0$, so all the orbits must move down vertically. Since there can't be any periodic or heteroclinic/homoclinic orbit solutions, these orbits must converge to a point on the x-axis, and this point is trivially an equilibrium point. Now, for $\dot{x} < 0$, all the orbit on $X$ contains both an equilibrium point on the x-axis and the point $(x,1-x)$ for $x< \frac{1}{3}$, which has $\dot{y} < 0$, so $(x, 1-x)$ must go down (diagonally or vertically) and converge to an equilibrium on the x-axis.

Comment: can you please give me your thought on my argument in the comment right above?