# Polar coordinate system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the polar coordinates system: $\dot{r} = r(1-\frac{r^2(3+\cos{4\theta})}{4})$, $\dot{\theta} = 1 - \frac{r^2(\sin{4\theta})}{4}$. Prove the following statements:

(a) For $r<2$, all solutions are moving counterclockwise.

(b) Find max radius $r_1<2$ such that all solutions are crossing outward across $r_1$. Find the min radius $r_2 < 2$ such that all solutions are crossing inward across $r_2$

(c) There is a periodic orbit somewhere in the annulus $r_1\leq r\leq r_2$

**My attempt:** For part (a), I was able to show $\dot{\theta} > 0$ for $r<2$, so $\theta(t)$ is strictly increasing. Thus, all solutions must move counterclockwise.

For the other two parts, after quite sometime, I still cannot get any ideas how to approach them. Can anyone please help with either part (b) or (c)?

Comment: You may want to check if it is possible to get a 2nd order ODE for $r$, whose coefficients will tell about the behavior of $r(t)$.

Comment: @AmeyJoshi: Great comment. I think I can rewrite it as a 2nd order ODE of the form: $r'' - r'(r^2g(\theta)) + rf(\theta) = 0$. What does the coefficient imply then?

Comment: @Variable: how come you always can searched for GREAT links man(!?) Thank you so much for those files, as I enjoyed it quite much! Honestly, I figured out how to solve part (c) by Poincare-Bendixson after reading through a word document about limit cycle that contains the same problem $4$ as in your first pdf file. Do you mind reviewing my arguments for the first part of part (b) in this problem (I asked Mr. Israel for his thought, but he forgot me:P) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580358/invariant-sets-of-planar-system-odes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dr}{dt} = r(1-\frac{r^2(3+\cos{4\theta})}{4})$$
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt} = 1 - \frac{r^2(\sin{4\theta})}{4}$$
$$\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\frac{r(1-\frac{r^2(3+\cos{4\theta})}{4})}{1 - \frac{r^2(\sin{4\theta})}{4}}$$ 
The maximum and minimum values of $r$ are obtained when $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=0$, so in case of : 
$$1-\frac{r_e^2(3+\cos{4\theta_e} )}{4}=0$$
where $r_e$ means an extremum of $r$ and $\theta_e$ means a particular value of $\theta$ corresponding to the extremum of $r$. 
$$r_e=2\sqrt{\frac{1}{3+\cos{4\theta_e}}}$$
$r_1=2\sqrt{\frac{1}{3+1}}=1$ and $r_2=2\sqrt{\frac{1}{3-1}}=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm so dumb...But how do we know that "all solutions are crossing outward across $r_1$" or "all solutions are crossing inward across $r_2$"? These are the major parts that confused me when I tried to solve this problem:(

Comment: i'm sorry but you probably realized that it's not possible to solve directly from $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$... can you show your solution please?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you on this point because I don't know how translate in French "crossing outward across" and "crossing inward across".

Comment: I think I got part (c) now: from part (b), any solution curve $(r(t), \theta(t))$ must have a point in the annulus between two circles with radius $r_1$ and $r_2$ found in part (b) such that this point is an attractor. This means that for sufficiently large $t_1<\infty$, the solution $(r(t_1), \theta(t_1))$ converges to this point. We define the periodicity = $t_1$ (Q.E.D)